# Remove floor plans from Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, building

I am creating an Android application that uses the Google Maps API.  I've set the MapType to Satellite so it will not show any labels, but it still shows the Google Maps floor plans when I zoom into an area that has them.  Is there a way to make sure they don't appear and I just get the satellite image?

Answer (score 3):

The only options we have for removing labels is using `setMapType(MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)` or `setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NONE)`. Indoor plans can be removed with `setIndoorEnabled(false)`.